# How to use ALT to send Escape in Vim

Tags: vim

According to "[Avoid the escape key](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key)" many terminals send the Escape key with the <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd> modifier key
yet there are terminals where this behavior is not present.

Is there a way get <kbd>Alt</kbd> to send an Escape in Vim regardless of the terminal defaults?
I found tips for the opposite but none about this so far.

Comment: When linking to something, use more descriptive text than "click here" or "this...". "[Don’t use “click here” And other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)". Also, grammar is important on Stack Overflow so please use proper capitalization. SO isn't a message board, it's an online reference.

Comment: indeed thank you for the edits and the tips

Comment: Thanks, but it's not necessary to thank us. SO is a labor of love, we're just trying to pay it forward for what we've gained over the years.

Comment: Are you asking, "How do I use Alt as an additional Escape key such that it works without typing another key?" or, "How do I configure my terminal emulator to make Alt key combinations send a sequence with Escape in it?"

Comment: @bk2204 there are terminals that send escape with alt combinations, for example alt+x would be the same as pressing Escape followed by x
i'm looking for a way for vim to always act like that

Comment: @Fuseteam Did you find a way how to do it ? Or it's impossible ?

Comment: @VanechikSpace i have not found a way to do it yet, many terminals do do this tho, might be a matter of requests that don't do this, to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key mapping to your .vimrc:

```
" Alternate escape
map § <Esc>
imap § <Esc>
```

In order to find what characters map to your Alt, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> in insert mode.

---

It appears that <kbd>Alt</kbd> by itself is not mappable, you have to combine it with another key.

Comment: yes i realized that but 96 mappings sounds a bit like overkill :p